# Is there a functionality to combine karate-config.js files from multiple projects into a single file in karate?

Tags: karate

We have two projects with the structure test -> project1 -> karate-config.js and test ->project2 ->karate-config.js. Ideally i would like to combine the configs into a single config file at the test folder level like test ->karate-config.js ( project1 + project2). Both projects use a similar structure in the config file except for the the API endpoint URL's. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read any JS function at any time and evaluate it. If it returns a JSON, you can use `karate.merge()` to add it to the config. So that gives you many possibilities.

```
var fun = read('classpath:some.js');
config = karate.merge(config, fun());
```

That said please be aware that there is a concept of `karate-base.js` - so please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-basejs