# How to have two karate-config.js in the same project and use the variables from two karate-config.js file in the feature file

Tags: karate

How to have two karate-config.js in the same project and use the variables from two karate-config.js file in the feature file and need to overwrite the value in the runtime in both config.js file.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of "environment specific config" see if that fits your needs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#environment-specific-config

Else see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130175/143475

Otherwise please assume that what you ask is not supported.